# Firebase security read and write rules

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am changing the firebase security rules from

```
allow write: if true;
```

to

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid !=null;
```

but it only works if the user signed in via username and password auth BUT if the user signs in via google sign in, it does not allow the user to write into the DB.

Any help???
Thanks

```
allow write: ????????    to allow the user signed in via google sign in to access the DB
```

Once a button is pressed, this function is called

```
login() {
     googleSignIn.signIn();
  }
```

In the initState, this code is listening to the login

```
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen(      
      (account) {
        functionToSignin(account);
      },
      onError: (err) {
        print('Error signing in: $err');
      },
    );

    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then(
      (account) { functionToSignin(account);
      },
    ).catchError((err) { print('Error');   
    });

//-----
functionToSignin(account) async {
    if (account != null) {
      print('got an account from google');
      print('User signed in: $account');
      await addUserInFirestore();// call this function to create and add //users in DB firestore**** 

      setState(() {
        isAuth = true; 
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false; 
      });
    }
  }
```

The code that query the DB is:

```
final userReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
final userr = googleSignIn.currentUser;
DocumentSnapshot doc = await userReference.doc(userr?.id).get();

if (!doc.exists) {
userReference .doc(userr?.id).set({
        "id": userr?.id,        
      });

doc = await userReference .doc(userr?.id).get();
```

Thank you so much for your time and help!!

Comment: Please share the code you're using to sign in the user that's not working the way you expect.  Also share the code that performs the query and show us that the Firebase user's UID is set just before you execute the query.  We should be able to reproduce the issue using the code and instructions you provide.

Comment: The `if request.auth.uid !=null` is no different between sign-in providers, so the rules should be the same. Most likely the problem is in how you sign in, which is why we'll need to see the code that Doug asked for. In general, please ready [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-examples to learn how to increase the chances we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase security rules only work when the user is signed in using Firebase Authentication.  It seems you are using the Google signin SDK directly, which will not work at all with security rules.  If you want the user to sign in using Google while also using security rules, you must follow the instructions for [allowing Google sign-ins with Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth).  This will create a Firebase Auth user account that's linked to their Google account.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to do that and get back to you. I feel this is the issue.
Should I place this function once the user login?

Comment: I think you should first just follow the instructions in the documentation.